# Programmatically turn off Google AdMob Ads (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, admob, ads

I am using Google AdMob for iOS:

[Google AdMob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals)

I was wondering whether I'm able to turn off these ads programmatically so they stop displaying. After reading through the SDK I can't see anywhere to toggle the ads on or off.

**EDIT:**

This is how I load the Google AdMob code:

**MainViewController.m**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
    // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    // Must be a better way to position at bottom of page
    [bannerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width/2, 455)];
    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    // remove this line when you are ready to deploy for real
    request.testing = YES;
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
}
```

I'd like to disable the superview within a class implementation:

This is the code I've tried so far to loop through the `MainViewController` subviews.

Once I've found the right subview `GADBannerView` I want to be able to remove it.

**OtherClass.m**

```
- (void)disableAds
{
    // Turn the ads off.
    UIViewController *mainView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    for (UIView *subview in [mainView.view subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"View(s): %@", subview);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not just set `bannerView_ ` to nil?

Comment: Updated original question with further code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the class implementation was actually a plugin I was able to use the following code:

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.viewController.view subviews]) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[GADBannerView class]]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

According to Phonegap documentation, every plugin has a `self.viewController` property. So it was just a matter of looping through and removing only the `GADBannerView` from the superview.

Of course I had to `#import "GADBannerView.h"` in the plugin class implementation first so it knew about `GADBannerView`.

Comment: you are assigning your banner view to a ivar, you just can call removeFromSuperview on that. see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

without any experience with admob I would say just disable the BannerView and any controller

like `bannerView = nil` or `[bannerView release]`

also `[bannerView removeFromSuperview]` or `bannerView.hidden = YES`

---

from your own answer, and your added code, all you need to do is

```
 -(void)disableAds
{
    // Turn the ads off.
    [bannerView_ removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, see there's one `MainViewController` in my application and within another implementation I'd like to remove a subview of `MainViewController`. That subview is `GADBannerView`.

Comment: use either delegation or notifications. for a better answer you will have to post some code, so that it is clear, how the classes stick together.

Comment: but you will find plenty of post here asking how different controllers can communicate with each other.

Comment: Your `disableAds()` method will not work because `bannerView_` is not exposed to any class implementation outside of MainViewController. I had to loop through the `self.viewController` property of MainViewController and remove that `bannerView_` subview for the `GADbannerView` class object. See my own answer for an example of what I ended up doing.

Comment: your solution is not very elegant. instead you could use either a notification or a singleton class that holds the reference to the bannerView. you have full control over the view hierarchy. looping over every view and perform rather expensive runtime-involved operations is just not needed, and indicate a possible architectural issue.

Comment: Up-vote for valid point. We are looking into using a singleton class or notification. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `bannerView.rootViewController = nil;`