# Instantly remove AdMob banner?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, admob, banner

I've made a game in using cocos2d and have integrated an admob banner in the appdelegate so that it is displayed on all view controllers. Ive implemented a remove ads feature which happens in the "game over" screen. Here is my problem. The remove ads function works but does not take affect immediately. I have to kill the app and restart it for the banner to go away. Is there a way to just reload the appdelegate and the ads are removed instantly instead of having to reload the app? PLEASE HELP This is driving me crazy.

EDITED: HERE IS MY CURRENT CODE. THE BANNER LOADS WHEN THE APP LOADS I AM TRYING TO MAKE THE BANNER GO AWAY WHEN THE USER PURCHASES TO REMOVE IT WITHOUT HAVING TO RESTART THE APP(CLOSE THE APP RESTART)

AppDelegate.h

```
    #import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"


// Added only for iOS 6 support
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController <CCDirectorDelegate>
@end
@class RootViewController;
@class GADBannerView, GADRequest;
@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,ADBannerViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate, GameCenterManagerDelegate,ChartboostDelegate,GADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window_;
    MyNavigationController *navController_;

    CCDirectorIOS   *director_;
    UIViewController    *tempVC;                        // weak ref
    RootViewController *viewController_;

    //Admob
    GADBannerView *bannerView_;
    BOOL isAdPositionAtTop_;
}
```

AppDelegate.m  i use calladmob to start ads if removeads is "no"

```
-(void)callAdMob{
//Admob ads
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,self.window.frame.size.height -CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height);
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait origin:origin];
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"idhere";
bannerView_.delegate = self;
[bannerView_ setRootViewController:tempVC];
CGRect adBannerViewFrame = [bannerView_ frame];
int lSizeValue=0;
if([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width==320)
    lSizeValue=50;
else if([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width==768)
    lSizeValue=66;
adBannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
adBannerViewFrame.origin.y = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height-lSizeValue;
[bannerView_ setFrame:adBannerViewFrame];
[[self navController].view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[self createRequest]];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not send a notification from your "remove ads" function?

And then anywhere you have an AdMob banner, you can add an observer that watches for that notification and the method that gets called would do something like:

[`[bannerView removeFromSuperview]` or `bannerView.hidden = YES`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313219/programmatically-turn-off-google-admob-ads-ios)

provided you have your AdMob banner connected to an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: My banner loads the moment the app loads and stays up in all view controllers. The only place i have code for the banner is in the appdelegate. What you recommended will not work.

Comment: you probably need to edit your question to better describe how your banner is added then, and also show if there is any kind of IBOutlet connected to it.